# how to expand or collaps a div line on another div, with change of height?

Tags: css, vue.js, expand, fieldcollapsing

I want to do the same work but with two lignes and when I clic on the button the second line takes all the table space, I don't know why it doesn't work

this code is working, but with twos columns,

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table">
      <div :class="{ 'column1-expanded': expanded }" class="column column1">
        <div class="item">colonne 1</div>
      </div>

      <button class="toggle-button" @click="toggleColumns">+</button>
      <div class="column column2">
        <div class="item">colonne 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      expanded: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleColumns() {
      this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh; /* Hauteur de l'écran */
  width: 100vw;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
.table {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 35vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
 

.column {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition: flex 0.3s;
}

.column1-expanded {
  flex: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: flex 0.3s, width 0.3s, padding 0.3s;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.toggle-button {
  background-color: #aea9a1;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

[before the clic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcKeO.png)
[after the clic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObGGy.png) <-- here is the problem, I want that the seconde line takes all the space ,

Comment: The button```+``` is causing the space.